# inject dependency in OnMessageReceived during token validation

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-7.0, bearer-token

In the process of validating the bearer token in the OnMessageReceived method, I want to get access to one of my services. I can create an instance of it manually, but I would like to use the built-in dependency injection mechanism. How can I do that? I can't find any suitable way through the provided TokenValidatedContext.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddJwtTokenAuthentication(this 
   IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
      services.Configure<JwtConfig> 
   (configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings"));
  services.AddAuthentication(x =>
   {
      x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;                
  })
   .AddJwtBearer(x =>
                          {

 x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
            {

             OnMessageReceived = c =>
             {
               var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
               var fooService = sp.GetService<IFooService>();
               return Task.CompletedTask;
             }
           }
```